# .csv file data checking using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file with the following data

Roll,Subject,Marks,Pass_Fail
1,A,50,P
1,B,50,P
1,C,30,F
1,D,50,P
2,A,40,P
2,B,30,F
2,C,30,F
2,D,50,P
3,A,50,P
3,B,30,F
3,C,40,P
3,D,20,F
4,A,50,P
4,B,50,P
4,C,50,P
4,D,50,P

Now, I would like to check if any person has failed in both B & C or D

Output -
2,B,30,F
2,C,30,F
3,B,30,F
3,D,20,F

I am new to Python. I have used Pandas. But only able to get the unique Roll value.
My code is as bellow

import pandas as pd

```
dataFrame = pd.read_csv(".\students.csv")
Unique_Users=dataFrame['roll'].unique()
for each roll in dataFrame:
 if dataFrame.loc['pass_fail'] == 'fail':
    print (dataFrame)
```

Answer (score 0):

*"to check if any person has failed in both B & C or D"*

Use dataframe filtering on specific conditions:

```
failed = df[df['Subject_Code'].isin(['B','C','D']) & df['Pass_Fail'].eq('F')]
print(failed)
```

---

```
   Roll Subject_Code  Marks Pass_Fail
6     2            C     20         F
7     2            D     25         F
```

Comment: Hello RomanPerekhrest, Thanks for the code. But isin[] will check for OR. I need to check if 'B' & ('C' || 'D')

Comment: @Anirban, you should have mentioned that you need to analyze rolls, not persons as was written in the question *"to check if any person has failed"*

Comment: a person is identified by the roll. The issue is, I am looking for all such rolls who have failed in subject "B" and "C" or "D". Not those who have failed in "B" || "C" || "D"

Comment: @Anirban, post the expected output

Comment: @Anirban, not here, it's not readable. Put iit n your question

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv(".\students.csv")
failed = df[(df['subject'].eq('B')) & df['pass_fail'].eq('fail')]
df1 = DataFrame(failed, columns= 
(['roll','name','subject','marks','pass_fail']))
for name in failed:
    failed_1 = df[df['subject'].isin('C','D') & df['pass_fail'].eq('fail')]
df2 = DataFrame(failed_1)
```